# How can I blacklist my inbuilt mic

Tags: linux, audio, devices

I tried to blacklist my inbuilt mic,
I also search on some other web site

They showed the command. "cat /proc/asound/modules"

I run it and I have the out put of

0 snd_hda_intel
1 snd_hda_intel

If added to the blacklist "snd_hda_intel", it also blacklist my sound card.
And also I tried put like this
"blacklist 1 snd_hda_intel"
But it doesn't work.

Anyone help me how to blacklist my mic :(.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround that I use. Pick up an external USB soundcard and a headphone jack plug. In the mic part of the card plug in the headphone jack.

This makes the computer thinks its drawing audio from the usb, allows you to disable the external soundcard, and you'll still have working audio.

Comment: if your computer has a mic jack, then you could try plugging a headphone jack into that

Answer (score 0):

blacklisting audio device will lose all playback and capture functions

should be possible to mute and reduce levels in `alsamixer` for internal mic or change capture to jack socket

may need to use <kbd>F6</kbd> to select correct device

and <kbd>F4</kbd>to see audio capture controls